# Compare two database in two different systems using ODT

Tags: database, oracle

I work on an Oracle database on a system which I am connected to remotely, I have a similar but not the same database in my local computer (in a virtual machine). I want to compare the two databases using ODT (Oracle Developer Tool) but it seems impossible since I don't have access to both database at the same time. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: You need to create a db link to query two DB at the same time - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083

Comment: "*Oracle Developer Tool*"? I have never heard of that. Do you happen to mean "*Oracle SQL Developer*"?

Comment: Depends what the detail level of differences you are looking for, but to run DESC (DESCRIBE) you don't need both DB's to be available the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the compare function of Oracle SQL Developer, you are supposed to be connected to a source and a destination database:

[image]

regards
Giova